# Files in iOS copied from bundle to cache folder have CreationDate and ModifiedDate of the compile

Tags: ios, copy, nsdate, nsfilemanager

I'm guessing my issue might be by design but I'm hoping there's a workaround.

My app is basically a document reader. A bunch of PDFs are pulled in and bundled with the app on compile. When the app is first run they're copied over (for users to add annotations and what not) and I generate a Dict for a UITableView (Using PDF metadata to populate things like the title). When a new version of the app is released I'd like to be a little smarter about copying files over during the upgrade process. Currently the best I can do is wipe everything out and copy anew.

The problem is that it seems that when Xcode copies the files into the bundle while compiling the NSFileCreationDate and NSFileModificationDate are both reset to when the app is compiled. This basically renders the whole date checking useless.

```
2012-10-11 15:19:29.254 handouts[5131:707] File attributes of source: {
NSFileCreationDate = "2012-10-11 19:19:10 +0000";
NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 501;
NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = mobile;
NSFileModificationDate = "2012-10-11 19:19:10 +0000";
NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
NSFileOwnerAccountName = mobile;
NSFilePosixPermissions = 420;
NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionNone;
NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
NSFileSize = 466028;
NSFileSystemFileNumber = 2754117;
NSFileSystemNumber = 234881027;
NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;
```

}

I'm currently planning on using file sizes and the dates in conjuncture, but I'm imagining it getting very messy, very fast. And I'll have to keep track of a bunch of the metadata on my own. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make Xcode honor the timestamps of the files it's copying?

I thought I'd check before getting too deep in the `if...then` code soup I'll likely be writing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK There's no way to get XCode to keep the dates. I ran into a similar issue and came up with a shell script to make a plist file that contained the modified dates of the files in a directory (recursively). I then include that in my bundle and read it when I copy files over to set the modified dates. You could modify this to handle creation or access dates or with some work a combination.

Here's the bash script: (I'm still new to bash, so please any comments on how to make it better are welcome)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#First parameter is the folder to recurse into, defaults to current directory
#Second parameter is the full path to a pList file without the extension, defaults to
#<CURRENT DIRECTORY>/fileInfo
#if you don't specify /'s in the parameter it will be treated as a domain instead and
#the pList will be elsewhere...

pinfoLoc=${2:-`pwd`/fileInfo}

#Useful for debugging
#echo Source: ${1:-.}
#echo Destination: $pinfoLoc

for i in ${1:-.}/*; do

  #Format: %Sa = last access, %Sm = last modified, %Sc = created
  date=`stat -f "%Sm" $i`

  #Uncomment below to see each file and date used
  #echo $i - $date

  #Write the data to the pList
  defaults write $pinfoLoc "$i" -date "$date" 

  #Recurse into directories, not sure if there's a better way to do this
  if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    bash $0 $i $pinfoLoc
  fi
done
```

Basically I have a folder called 'assets' that lives outside of the project and is linked to it and XCode will copy that folder into the bundle for me. Here is the code I came up with for updating the modified date of each file *AFTER* I had copied them over from the bundle.

```
//Update file properties
NSString *file, *dstPath, *srcPath;
NSDictionary *fAttribs;
NSData *fInfoData = [fm contentsAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileInfo" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary *fileInfo = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization
                                          propertyListWithData:fInfoData
                                          options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                                          format:&format
                                          error:&error];
NSString * resPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"assets"];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [fm enumeratorAtPath:resPath];
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject])
{
    NSLog(@"Directory Enum File: %@", file);
    dstPath = [NSString pathWithComponents:@[[appInfo appSupportPath], @"res", file ]];
    srcPath = [@"assets" stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    fAttribs = @{ NSFileModificationDate: [fileInfo valueForKey:srcPath]};
    [fm setAttributes:fAttribs ofItemAtPath:dstPath error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error setting attribute to file: %@ - %@", file, error.localizedDescription);
        [error release];
        error = nil;
    }
}
```

This is after my copy files method and there's a few variables you can't see. Namely `fm` is just the default manager from `NSFileManager`, `error` is an uninitialized `NSError`, `[appInfo appSupportPath]` is a static method that returns the directory where I store stuff on the device (since you can't modify the bundle).

Also I've hard coded the locations of the plist that holds the dates, and the directory that I've copied my files to, I'll probably update that in my code later.

The next thing I did was set up XCode to automate running my script and to also include the fileInfo.plist. The latter is easy once you have ran the script you can just drag and drop it into Xcode and keep it as a reference, the tricky part is getting it to run the script on each build.

1. Copy/paste my bash script above into a file
2. Click on your project in the Project Navigator
3. Select your target (Application name) under Targets if it isn't already selected
4. Click on the Build Phases tab
5. In the bottom right click Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script
6. The new phase will be the last thing, unfortunately that is **after** it has copied the files to the bundle, including the one we are generating. So drag the phase to just above 'Copy Bundle Resources'
7. For the shell I put /bin/bash, /bin/sh may work as well...
8. In the lines below I put this:

   ```
   pushd $PROJECT_DIR/..
   /PATH/TO/BASH/FILE/ABOVE.sh assets
   popd
   ```

   The `pushd $PROJECT_DIR/..` was needed as the assets directory is one level above my project, I could have hard coded the directory to go to instead and probably would be more clear.
9. If you try to build right now you will probably get a permission error as the script file doesn't have execute permissions. I don't know of an easier way on a Mac to set this than to open up terminal and run `chmod +x <BASH FILE NAME>` Yes I realize that allows everyone to execute it, if you're worried about it then play with the permissions, I'm not sure if XCode builds as a different user or what.

Hopefully at least some of this helps. I use this modified date to see if there are newer files on a web server and download only the ones I need.